# python won't recognice my function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have this weird problem where my program will give me this error message when I run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "\\srv-fons-02\USV_Home$\6357\inf\Phyton\classes test 1.py", line 38, in <module>
     time = Time(7, 61, 12)   File "\\srv-fons-02\USV_Home$\6357\inf\Phyton\classes test 1.py", line 8, in __init__
     self = int_to_time(int(self)) NameError: name 'int_to_time' is not defined
```

It tells me the function `int_to_time` isn't defined, while it is. I also only get this problem in my `__init__` and not in other places where I use it (`add_time` that gets used in `__add__` for example). I don't know why it does work with some functions. I have tried canceling the `int_to_time()` in `__init__` and didn't get an error message even tough I use `__add__`).

If anybody could help me that would be great, cause I am stuck atm.

This is my code:

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, hour=0, minute=0, second=0):
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
        self.second = second
        if not 0 <= minute < 60 and 0<= second < 60:
            self = int_to_time(int(self))

    def __str__(self):
        return '%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (self.hour, self.minute, self.second)

    def __int__(self):
        minute = self.hour * 60 + self.minute
        second = minute * 60 + self.second
        return int(second)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Time):
            return self.add_time(other)
        else:
            return self.increment(other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return other + int(self)


    def add_time(self, other):
        seconds = int(self) + int(other)
        return int_to_time(seconds)

    def increment(self, seconds):
        seconds += int(self)
        return int_to_time(seconds)
    """Represents the time of day.
    atributes: hour, minute, second"""

time = Time(7, 61, 12)

time2 = Time(80, 9, 29)

def int_to_time(seconds):
    time = Time()
    minutes, time.second = divmod(seconds, 60)
    time.hour, time.minute = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return time


print(time + time2)
print(time + 9999)
print(9999 + time)
```

Comment: Move this function before that class or add it as method.

Comment: You create your two ``Time`` objects BEFORE the definition of ``int_to_time()`` - so of course it isn't available during ``__init__()``.  When you start doing your additions, the function has been defined, so it works then.  Simply move the function up a few lines, just after the end of the class.

Comment: yeah, i saw it thx guys, also can you make a method that doesn't use the thing its a method of? and if so how? (i am still learning python and just started with classes)

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the invocation of `int_to_time` is made *before* the definition has been seen is the problem.

You initialize two `Time` objects before defining `int_to_time`:

```
time = Time(7, 61, 12)

time2 = Time(80, 9, 29)

def int_to_time(seconds):
    time = Time()
```

and inside `Time.__init__` you invoke `int_to_time` after a certain condition. If that condition is met, the call to `int_to_time` will fail.

Just moving the initialization *after* the definition suffices. Since `int_to_time` also seems closely related to your `Time` class it wouldn't be a bad idea to define it as a `@staticmethod` for that class and drop all worries about when the definition is made.

Comment: okay, that explains a lot haha, i should probably always initialize functions first, or intergrate them if possible